# Has the idea of holeum been debunked?

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holeum) is the wikipedia article. The basic idea is that the primordial density of microscopic black holes was high enough that many were able to form stable bound states before decaying through Hawking radiation (similarly to how unstable neutrons were able to form stable bound states with protons during BBN). These "holeums" would be dark matter candidates that would be much smaller than what is ruled out through gravitational lensing experiments (which rule out ordinary primordial black holes that must be large enough not to have evaporated already).

The [papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0308054) by Chavda that apparently introduced the idea are not well written or formatted, so I can understand why they are perhaps ignored. On the other hand the basic idea seems sounds to me. Is there a simple reason why it is not?

Comment: I don't think ignored is the right word. It did get through the peer review process and got published in CQG, so the theory has to have some quality. There is just so many theories of dark matter that it is hard to represent them fairly. Plus the holeum seems to have some very speculative features - for starters the bound state does not saturate the attractive force so your macro-holeum is not a bunch of short-range-force "atoms" but a horrible how-can-we-even-speculate-about-this-macroscopic-quantum-gravity-oleum.

Comment: Dead link at the start of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The big ticker is that no one really knows if evaporation of black holes will create stable planck-scale remnants, so the building blocks of holeum might not even exist. So until we've seen some black holes decay, and observed stable Planck-scale black holes formed, the hypothesis, though elegant, probably won't gain much traction.

Answer (score 1):

A theory stands or falls on the basis of its predictions. A unique achievement of the Holeum theory is the prediction that a gamma ray never comes with any neutrino. This is precisely the experimental finding of the Ice Cube experiment going on at the south pole. This finding has ruled out the well-known Fire Ball model. But it supports the Holeum model. The Fire Ball model predicted a simultaneous arrival of a neutrino along with a gamma ray. According to the Holeum model when a Holeum breaks up in the galactic halo due to its collision with another Holeum it emits bursts of Hawking radiation which is a black body radiation. It contains only the particles having electromagnetic interaction. This rules out the neutrinos that have only the weak interactions. There is no other theory to explain this finding. This is a unique support for the Holeum model. There are nearly half-a-dozen other predictions of the model that have received empirical support. For details please refer to "Unified Holeum Theory of Dark Matter and Dark Energy" in Research Gate.This model is still a work in progress. It is good to remember that it took the Higgs boson nearly four decades to be detected at CERN.

Answer (score 1):

My issue with the Holeum model is that it would fail to predict the current observations, and especially the CMB power-spectrum. Could microscopic primordial black holes exist? Yes. Could they have formed bound states in the early universe? Probably.
But here's the issue - CMB power spectrum predicts, with great accuracy, what the relative abundances of baryonic matter, dark matter, and dark energy in the universe are. This rules out the possibility of dark matter being made of Holeum, or any black hole derived theories for that matter. Simply because we know that dark matter is a different kind of form of matter than normal baryonic matter, and black holes are made of the baryonic matter themselves. So if the majority of dark matter in the universe were to in fact be Holeum, you would see that reflected in the CMB power-spectrum where the abundance of baryonic matter would increase.
I'm not saying that it cannot exist, I'm just saying that it cannot be the most abundant form of dark matter.

Comment: Primordial black holes are classed as non-baryonic dark matter, since they do not participate as baryons in primordial nucleosynthesis and interact only gravitationally.